# VBA Runtime Error 1004 when protecting sheet

Tags: vba, excel

The following code is meant to run on a protected sheet but when I go to reprotect it after running the code, I get error 1004 "Application-defined or object-defined error" on the lines of code that have Range or Cell. I don't get this error if I don't reprotect the sheet afterwards though. Any help?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim KeyCells, KeyCells2 As Range

    With Sheets(2)
        .Unprotect Password:="xyz"
        Set KeyCells = .Range("U5")
        If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, .Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
            lastrow = FindLastRow("*")
           .Range("T8:T" & lastrow) = .Range("U5")
            For i = 8 To lastrow
                If .Cells(i, "R") > .Cells(i, "T") Then
                    .Cells(i, "U").Value2 = IIf(.Cells(i, "R") > .Cells(i, "S"), Cells(i, "R"), Cells(i, "S"))
                Else
                    .Cells(i, "U").Value2 = IIf(.Cells(i, "T") > .Cells(i, "S"), .Cells(i, "T"), Cells(i, "S"))
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    End With

    Call PS3.ProtectSheet

End Sub
```

Comment: Please indent your code to make it more readable.

Comment: What is `PS3.ProtectSheet`? Why not just reverse what you had at the start, `Sheets(2).Protect Password:="xyz"`.

Comment: So, in reading your question, the error does not happen in the code that is displayed? BTW, you are not clear if this code protects/unprotects the sheet that `Worksheet_Change` is on - you can just use `Me.` to reference the target sheet and then this code is transportable to whatever sheet you want (what if `Sheets(2)` is now `Sheets(3)` and your change code is not working on the sheet you think it is?).

Comment: Not related to the problem, but change `Dim KeyCells, KeyCells2 As Range` to `Dim KeyCells as Range, KeyCells2 As Range`., for now 1st variable is declared as `Variant`.